While fetching data from SQL Server table to Datalake, column values are getting truncated
We are using AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) to fetch data from a SQL Server table to Datalake in Athena.
The DMS process is working fine and data is getting added to Datalake.
But one of the columns in table is getting truncated. This column has JSON values.

Column datatype in SQL Server source table is nvarchar(MAX)

Column datatype which Datalake is adding in Athena: string

Column length in SQL Server source table: 46,728

Column length which Datalake is adding in Athena: 16,385


Is it a limitation of DMS service?

Athena provides an SQL-like experience on top of S3. As far as DMS is concerned (ref Best practices for AWS Database Migration Service) it uses "Limited LOB mode" against Redshift and S3 targets. The default size limit for LOB values in Limited LOB mode is 32KB which would be around 16,384 characters for an nvarchar data type (assuming 2 bytes/character).

@AlwaysLearning Why are you answering in a comment rather then posting an answer?

You can turn on FullLobMode and turn off LimitedSizeLobMode in the TargetMetadata settings of the DMS task setting file. Note that there may be a performance issue with pulling tables with gobs of blobs. It is potentially a multiple round trip per record type of penalty.
If your migration does not need these blobs, then you can simply truncate them at 32Kb.
